# How to do a ngIf based on a promise in angular?

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to do a ngIf where the result is depending on a promise.

The template

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="carValue" name="carName">
    <option value="renault">Renault</option>
    <option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
  </select>
  <p *ngIf="isDisplayed()">Good choice!</p>
</div>
```

So far, the function isDisplayed is

```
isDisplayed() {
  return this.carValue === 'bmw';
}
```

But I'd like it to be asynchronous. Something like

```
isDisplayed() {
  return this.getBestChoice().then((result) => result);
}

getBestChoice() {
  // fake http call
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('bmw'), 3000);  
  });
}
```

Obviously it won't work. I have ideas how to implement this but not sure it is clean.

- Bind an event ngModelChange. Each time user pick a new car. It reloads a variable "isDisplayed"
- Save the promise and use aync pipe in the template. But it won't reload the data.

Here is a [punker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ti2oCfWbgYTQqAEEzHRa?p=preview).

Comment: Just have a `displayed` property in your component, that the async method updates, and use `*ngIf` on it? It's usually considered bad practice to call methods in `*ngIf`/`*ngFor`/etc. btw.

Comment: Is the best choice changing over time ? Do you have to refetch it every time the user change is choice in the select ?

Comment: @all I need the 'bestChoice' to be reloaded each time a car is selected

Comment: @Clemzd, Why not use a variable? this.getBestChioce().then(result=>this.variable=result), and *ngIf="variable"

Comment: @Eliseo a variable will work for the first call but if the user change the car it won't call the promise again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not go with Observables, it's the Angular way. You can just set one as a public property and run it throught AsyncPipe which'll handle sub/unsub and change detection triggering for you.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { map, share, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  carValue = '';
  showCongrats$: Observable<boolean>;
  check() {
    // fake API call
    this.showCongrats$ = timer(1000).pipe(
      map(() => 'bmw'), // "API" says bmw rocks
      tap(console.log),
      map(bestCar => this.carValue === bestCar),
      share() // so multiple async pipes won't cause multiple API calls
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="carValue" (change)="check()">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="renault">Renault</option>
    <option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
  </select>
    <p *ngIf="showCongrats$|async">Good Choice!</p>
    <p *ngIf="carValue && (showCongrats$|async) === false">Not the Best Choice!</p>
</div>
```

Working stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxcq89?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Downvoted this answer because there's no need to use an observable which is more complex and takes more code. For something that only fires a single event, promises are often a better choice and async pipes can handle it.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it like this:

class.ts

```
export class FieldHeaderSectionComponent implements OnInit {
  hasBody: Promise<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.hasBody = this.haveBody();
  }
  
  public haveBody() : Promise<boolean> {
    // ... logic
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }  
}
```

template.html

```
<div *ngIf="hasBody | async">...</div>
```

Comment: Like this solution. Simple and direct.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The async pipe takes Promises and the accepted answer forces you to create an observable which is unnecessarily more complex.